# Taskkill doesn't seems to kill process

Tags: java, windows, runtime.exec, taskkill

I am beginner in Java.

I have developed my own task-killer in *Java* for **Windows OS**.

Source Code goes something like :

```
public class MyTaskKiller 
{
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
     {
          Runtime rt=Runtime.getRuntime();
          rt.exec("taskkill /f /im mintty.exe");
          rt.exec("taskkill /f /im conhost.exe");
          rt.exec("taskkill /f /im bash.exe");
          rt.exec("taskkill /f /im HPNetworkCommunicatorCom.exe");
          rt.exec("taskkill /f /im AsusTPHelper.exe");
          .
          .
          .
          rt.exec("taskkill /f /im CCleaner.exe");
          rt.exec("taskkill /f /im unsecapp.exe");
     }
 }
```

Before I Run my task-killer , There are around many processes running as you can see in the screenshot below : (I have hard-coded all processes name where user name is "owner")
[image: I have hard-coded all processes name where user name is "owner"]

After I run my code , the code finishes executing still some processes are running (not getting killed).

Screenshot of Task Manager after running my program :
[image: Many Processes are still Running]

I have checked all the spellings , there are no mistakes in spellings !

Yet I don't understand why all the mentioned processes are not getting killed !

Can someone please help me ? What should i change in my code to kill all the processes in my list (Forcefully shutdown that process if required !)

I can provide the whole source code if required!

Comment: Some processes can be set to automatically restart, such as those executed by a service.  Could they be being stopped then restarted before you can see?

Comment: To continue that point: You should be able to see whether they are by looking at the process IDs. They should change if the process was restarted (or look at the time when they were started, but that column isn't displayed by default).

Comment: You should also kill the childprocesses `/T`. And there can be restrictions on the processes you try to kill. (userwise )

Comment: You may need to run this code as an admin to make it work.